# Existence of limit in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove for a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, its limit at 0 exists. Is it enough to prove that the limit exists and same if we approach $0$ through the all the lines starting at $0$ of various slopes? Thanks.

Comment: No you would have to prove that the limit exists and is the same for all "incoming" paths to $0$. Which include the lines but all other kinds of paths too ...

Comment: ya. I am also thing so. is there any examples suggesting that this is not sufficient? I cant find such one. thanks.

Comment: @GArunkumar : Any decent calculus textbook will have a counterexample showing that this is not true.  Do you have such a book?

Comment: I am studying complex analysis. I am reading Ahlfors. I have Apostal's calculus book both the volumes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example showing that this is not enough. Define function $u$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ like this:
$$
f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    (1,1) & \mathrm{if}\ y=x^2\ \mathrm{and}\ x \neq 0 \\
    (0,0) & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}\right.
$$

If we approach point $(0,0)$ along a straight line, $f(x,y)$ almost always equals $(0,0)$ and converges to $(0,0)$. But $f$ does not have a limit at $(0,0)$.

Comment: thanks. nice example. similarly we can create lots of such example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f((x,y))=\begin{cases} (1,1) &\mbox{if } y=x^2\  and \ x\not =0\\ (0,0) &\mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$

If you consider only lines, the limit of $f$ at $0$ will be $(0,0)$.

But actually, this function is not continuous because, however small disk you take around $(0,0)$, $f$ takes both values $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.